# Test in mocha not completing if shareReplay operator of RxJS is used

Tags: visual-studio-code, rxjs, mocha.js

I have a simple Javascript function that returns an observable to which I have applied the `shareReplay` operator with parameter 1.

```
[![export function doStuffWithShareReplay() {
    return interval(100).pipe(
        shareReplay(1),
        tap(d => console.log('do stuff 1', d)),
        take(5)
    );
}
```

If I put such function within a **mocha** test and run it from within VSCode, it seems that the execution of the test never completes and I have to stop the test execution manually. More precisely, the test passes as expected, but the small control pad at the top-center of VScode is not closed and I have to click on the red button to close it, as you can see in the following picture. If I remove `shareReplay` the execution ends as expected. I am wondering which is the reason of the behavior.

[image: VSCode window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `publishReplay(1)` and `refCount()` instead of `shareReplay(1)`:

```
return interval(100).pipe(
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount(),
  ...
```

There's a bug in `shareReplay(1)` since RxJS 5.5 (that still exists in RxJS 6.1) that prevents it from unsubscribing from its source.

For more details see this issue: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3336